PyQt5 и folium проблемы с выводом карты с помошью виджета
простая стандартная программа вывода карты фолиум в qWidget не показывает карту. если сохранять карту в html все в браузере работает, любые виджеты PyQt5 сами по себе работают исправно. Программа завершается без ошибок. ОС линукс минт. Может кто сталкивался.
(в отчете о системе при запуске обнаружил такую строчку: "Пакет, содержащий /home/lenovo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess не найден."
код:
import io
import sys
import folium
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = folium.Map(
        location=[45.5236, -122.6750],  zoom_start=13
    )

    data = io.BytesIO()
    m.save(data, close_file=False)
    w = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    w.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



Проблема решена удалением Pyqt5 и PyqtWebEngine. не понял как, но почему-то эти пакеты дублировались в системе.

В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
